# IntelliJ Android cannot attach debugger

Tags: android, debugging

Got a project recently converted to Gradle. Now I cannot debug the application.

I run the `Debug Configuration` - the app starts with a popup "Waiting for Debugger".

So I try to press the "Attach debugger to process"-button, select my process and nothing happens. Instead I get a

Unable to open debugger port `java.net.connectexception` *"Operation Timed Out"*.

Anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you trying to debug in the emulator or on a device?

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my part it was related to the internal networking. It seemed that

debugger <-> localhost connection couldn't be resolved. I was hinted by browsing through answers and executing `lsof -i :8671` which was the debugger port for that session

```
idea    2244 username   41u  IPv4 0xe6ebe70eee4e0cd      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.74:54808->hajders:8617 (SYN_SENT)
```

As you can see the state was stuck SYN_SENT, which means the TCP connection could not be established. I added the following to my `/etc/hosts` file `127.0.0.1 hajders`.